# Invalid VPN Secrets! No Server Certificate Verification Method Enabled

Tags: network-manager, proxy, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I'm trying to set up a vpn (from VyperVPN) with OpenVPN and keep getting an invalid VPN Secrets error. I've been searching for a solution for a day and a half mow to no avail so i though i would come ask the pros.

I tried restarting network manager as well as the whole system. Also I tried ticking/unticking the all users option in open vpn. both were said to have helped others with this problem.

Heres the syslog:

```
Dec 16 14:33:13 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Dec 16 14:33:13 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3111
Dec 16 14:33:13 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Dec 16 14:33:13 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN connection 'VyprVPN OpenVPN' (Connect) reply received.
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 x86_64-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Feb 27 2013
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: LZO compression initialized
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Dec 16 14:33:14 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]216.168.3.151:1194
Dec 16 14:33:17 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: [us2.vpn.giganews.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]216.168.3.151:1194
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: AUTH: Received AUTH_FAILED control message
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC nm-openvpn[3117]: SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 0
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 10
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Dec 16 14:33:20 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> Policy set 'ervilla_EXT' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec 16 14:33:25 Penguine-PC NetworkManager[920]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

After reviewing the logs it would appear the problem is "No server certificate verification method has been enabled." to quote directly from the log. To be honest though i dont know what to make of that, hopefully someone with more know how can inform me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `No server certificate verification method has been enabled.` is the source of the problem. But I fixed this warning by selecting "Verify name exactly" for the option "Server Certificate Check"

To the "Subject Match" field I entered "OpenVPN Server".

Here I paste the screenshot:
[image]

But regarding the error message `AUTH: Received AUTH_FAILED control message` I'd say that your VPN credentials are invalid or you have selected the wrong authentication type. And this seem to be the real issue.